# cloud foundry uploading error

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry, vmc

Get the below error on doing `vmc push`

```
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - C:/DOCUME~1/lihengxu/LOCALS~1/Temp/.vmc_blog_files/E:
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `fu_mkdir'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:217:in `mkdir_p'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:215:in `mkdir_p'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:201:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:201:in `mkdir_p'
cfoundry-0.4.19/lib/cfoundry/zip.rb:27:in `unpack'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_entry_set.rb:35:in `each'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_entry_set.rb:35:in `each'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_central_directory.rb:109:in `each'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_file.rb:132:in `foreach'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_file.rb:90:in `open'
rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_file.rb:131:in `foreach'
cfoundry-0.4.19/lib/cfoundry/zip.rb:24:in `unpack'
cfoundry-0.4.19/lib/cfoundry/upload_helpers.rb:58:in `prepare_package'
cfoundry-0.4.19/lib/cfoundry/upload_helpers.rb:42:in `upload'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:119:in `upload_app'
interact-0.5.1/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:118:in `upload_app'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:100:in `setup_new_app'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:82:in `push'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `send'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `run'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `invoke'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:113:in `call'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:113
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/callbacks.rb:74:in `with_filters'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:112
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in `execute'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in `execute'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start'
vmc-0.4.7/bin/vmc:11
C:/Ruby187/bin/vmc:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/vmc:23
```

Comment: Please try uninstalling all versions of vmc and reinstalling.

Comment: It didn't work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do other vmc commands work?

Are you able to try running this on Ruby 1.9?

Comment: i was running this on Ruby 1.9.3 and 1.8.7  .vmc version test 0.3.x to 0.4.7.  all version test failed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
gem install vmc --pre
```

Comment: Henry, Can you tell us what type of application are you deploying to Cloud Foundry? Is it a Ruby app, Java app, or node app? Also can you give us the vmc version a long with cfoundry version which you have installed and are using. vmc -v will give you the vmc version and gem list cfoundry should give you the version for cfoundry.